# Date Format with JsRender

Tags: javascript, jsrender

I am using the following code to see the date value of variable {{:Tag}}. This shown with this Format 2020-03-27. But I want to have this as 27.03.2020. 
Could you please advise where to start or where can I find a similar code to have it formated?

```
<td class="tg-imwf" colspan="8">Abschlusstag:  {{:Tag}}</td>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with jsRender but after briefly looking at the documentation, it looks like you can do this logic in the render method for the tag.

You can do this and it should work fine:

```
value.split('-').reverse().join(".")
```

EDIT:  If you would like for me to help you solve the render method fully, just copy paste the pertinent code and I'll knock it out for you.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to change the date format to "dd.mm.yyyy". The current one is "yyyy-mm-dd". Any idea?

Comment: Where is that date being generated from?  Can you show me the code that is rendering the Tag value? Basically, where is the javascript at?  That is where you need to format your date.

Comment: It is generated with an app (PhpMaker) and the value is comming from MySql. The app is supporting JQuery too..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem with the following code:

```
<td class="tg-imwf" colspan="8">Abschlusstag:  {{{Tag}}}</td>
```

thanks a lot for your conribution.

mpol_ch